# AppFabric Auto Start + WCF - Server Reboot Exceptions

Tags: wcf, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, appfabric

My Server setup is Windows Server R2, IIS 7.5, AppFabric

I have my WCF services enabled to Auto-Start.

When the servers restarted over night, the services fail with following error in Event Log.

```
    WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/12036987
 Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/Host/emailservice.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: An item with the same key has already been added.. ---> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedTransportConfigurationManager.EnsureInitialized()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedTransportConfigurationManager.InternalGetBaseAddresses(String virtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath)
 Process Name: w3wp
 Process ID: 2540
```

It looks like AppFabric not handling threading, any one having similar issue or workaround?

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue. Did you ever figure out what was wrong?